# Cannot use jquery within react-native - get the error: document.createElement is not a function

Tags: jquery, react-native

I'm attempting to use jquery within **react-native**, purely for it's dom parsing/traversal abilities.  The particular use case is to scrape an external website and parse it.

When I require jquery in my code, as in:

```
var jquery = require('jquery');

var someHtmlIveDownloaded = '<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>';

var jqueryElem = jquery(someHtmlIveDownloaded);
```

I get an error:
`document.createElement is not a function`

The top of the stack trace looks like:

```
Error: document.createElement is not a function
 stack: 
  assert              index.ios.bundle:86351
  Sizzle.setDocument  index.ios.bundle:86520
  <unknown>           index.ios.bundle:88015
  <unknown>           index.ios.bundle:88070
  arr                 index.ios.bundle:85487
  <unknown>           index.ios.bundle:85499
  require             index.ios.bundle:245
  <unknown>           index.ios.bundle:47852
  require             index.ios.bundle:245
  <unknown>           index.ios.bundle:47829
```

The assert line it originates from is:

```
/**
 * Support testing using an element
 * @param {Function} fn Passed the created div and expects a boolean result
 */
function assert( fn ) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
```

How can I use jquery to parse external html in react-native?

Answer (score 0):

[Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) may be an alternative to jQuery. It's built on top of [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2/) and provides a subset of jQuery API.

I've made it work in my sample project. However, the performance may be a bottleneck of the JS FPS since React Native also calculates UI layout on the same JS thread.

In my sample project when running on a Nexus 5 with Android 6.0,

```
cheerio.load(html);
```

may take ~130ms when parsing a 25KB html page and more than 1 second for a 250KB html page. The JS FPS drops to 0 ~ 10 during the call. Since there's no easy way to break the parsing into small tasks, I ended up moving the networking and parsing work to native code.